# Any substantial benefit of using machine mode in xperf output for further parsing by custom utility?

Tags: windows, xperf, wpr

So I'm trying to process performance data recorded with WPR and processed to .csv format with xperf, and it has two modes, *-target human* and *-target machine*, I can see the difference is that machine mode seems to group events from the same timestamp into a single line or two, but does this have a real benefit when using a custom external utility for parsing this data?

I can see there may be a bit of less info in the machine version?

Human mode

```
Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime/CLRMethod/MethodUnloadVerbose,   12535888,          wpa.exe (8020),      11056,   3, , , , , 0x00007ffc4123c3f0, 0x00007ffc3f89ce80, 0x00007ffc40f09f30, 0x00000021, 0x0600067f, 8, "MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOCentralDirectoryFileHeader", "get_OffsetOfLocalHeader", "instance int64  ()", 6
Microsoft-Windows-RPC/RpcServerCall/win:Stop,   12535888,      svchost.exe (1100),       1912,   2, {e9934bb1-c880-48b5-a31b-5a99a27faade}, , , , 0x00000000
                  Stack,   12535888,       1912,   1, 0x00007ffcb01a5a04,        ntdll.dll!0x00007ffcb01a5a04
                  Stack,   12535888,       1912,   2, 0x00007ffcb016022c,        ntdll.dll!0x00007ffcb016022c
                  Stack,   12535888,       1912,   3, 0x00007ffcb0160059,        ntdll.dll!0x00007ffcb0160059
                  Stack,   12535888,       1912,   4, 0x00007ffcafe459ae,       rpcrt4.dll!0x00007ffcafe459ae
                  Stack,   12535888,       1912,   5, 0x00007ffcafe59c7a,       rpcrt4.dll!0x00007ffcafe59c7a
                  Stack,   12535888,       1912,   6, 0x00007ffcafdfa09c,       rpcrt4.dll!0x00007ffcafdfa09c
                  Stack,   12535888,       1912,   7, 0x00007ffcafe1438c,       rpcrt4.dll!0x00007ffcafe1438c
                  Stack,   12535888,       1912,   8, 0x00007ffcafe15beb,       rpcrt4.dll!0x00007ffcafe15beb
                  Stack,   12535888,       1912,   9, 0x00007ffcafe086ea,       rpcrt4.dll!0x00007ffcafe086ea
                  Stack,   12535888,       1912,  10, 0x00007ffcb01325fe,        ntdll.dll!0x00007ffcb01325fe
                  Stack,   12535888,       1912,  11, 0x00007ffcb01330d9,        ntdll.dll!0x00007ffcb01330d9
                  Stack,   12535888,       1912,  12, 0x00007ffcaff08364,     kernel32.dll!0x00007ffcaff08364
                  Stack,   12535888,       1912,  13, 0x00007ffcb0165e91,        ntdll.dll!0x00007ffcb0165e91
```

Machine Mode:

```
Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime/CLRMethod/MethodUnloadVerbose,   12535888,          wpa.exe (8020),      11056,   3, , , , , 0x00007ffc4123c3f0, 0x00007ffc3f89ce80, 0x00007ffc40f09f30, 0x00000021, 0x0600067f, 8, "MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOCentralDirectoryFileHeader", "get_OffsetOfLocalHeader", "instance int64  ()", 6
Microsoft-Windows-RPC/RpcServerCall/win:Stop,   12535888,      svchost.exe (1100),       1912,   2, {e9934bb1-c880-48b5-a31b-5a99a27faade}, , , , 0x00000000
                  Stack,   12535888,       1912, ntdll.dll!0x00007ffcb01a5a04, ntdll.dll!0x00007ffcb016022c, ntdll.dll!0x00007ffcb0160059, rpcrt4.dll!0x00007ffcafe459ae, rpcrt4.dll!0x00007ffcafe59c7a, rpcrt4.dll!0x00007ffcafdfa09c, rpcrt4.dll!0x00007ffcafe1438c, rpcrt4.dll!0x00007ffcafe15beb, rpcrt4.dll!0x00007ffcafe086ea, ntdll.dll!0x00007ffcb01325fe, ntdll.dll!0x00007ffcb01330d9, kernel32.dll!0x00007ffcaff08364, ntdll.dll!0x00007ffcb0165e91
```